# UIcollectionview list of horizontal toggle button in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I would like to create a list of horizontal buttons in UIcollectionview. Only one and only button can be selected and it will change to red color, problem is the selected cell will be reuse then there is possibility two red buttons appear in a same time, what should I do to solve this?

Comment: store your selected index as member variable, while cell reusing change the color by checking that stored selected index.

Comment: First of all try to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Store the index of the selected row in `didSelectRow` , then inside `cellForItemAt`

```
var selectedIndex = -1
var urlArr = [url1,url2,url3,url4,url5]
```

//

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier1, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! imagesCollectionViewCell
   let currentUrl = urlArr[indexPath.row]
   if(indexPath.row == selectedIndex)
  {
       // red
  }

  else
  {
      // default
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks bro for the accurate answer.
One more question, if let's say I have 5 cells to call different API, how do we differentiate which cell we click on?

Comment: by the way I think you need to call relsoaddata() on didselect and diddeselect method to see the changes on the cell

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create multiple toggle cells in UICollectionView then use this.

```
var selectedIndexes = NSMutableArray()
var items = [item1,item2,item3,item4,item5]
```

in cellForItemAt method. check for selected indexPath.row

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

   let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: yourIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! yourCell

  if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row){
     // make it active
  }else{
      // make it default
  }
}
```

And in didSelectItemAt method add and remove indexPath from the Array to toggle the button of cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  if selectedIndexes.contains(indexPath.row){
     selectedIndexes.add(indexPath.row)
  }else{
     selectedIndexes.remove(indexPath.row)
  }

    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: very good answer, just slightly change the index indicator into an array then become a multiple toggle instead of just select one cell.